Modern Day Central Vac tripping intermittently 1 to 2 minutes after starting
I recently had an MD 715H central vacuum system installed ( 14.9 amp max / 120 volts.)
It is on a dedicated circuit with a normal square D breaker 20 amp breaker. The power unit is in the Garage on a GFCI receptacle.
After a few weeks of being installed, every time I start the unit for the first time after being not used for a couple of days, after about 30 to 90 seconds the 20 amp breaker in the panel trips. Then after resetting the breaker, I could vacuum all day long without any more trouble. I came across a similar post by an user about 9 years back. Not sure if he had this resolved. One of the responses to the post talk about using High-Magnetic Breakers to Power CVSPU’s (Square D (#QO120HM) for a 20 amp circuit ). i don't know if the breaker i have is high magnetic one.
Any thoughts on how to resolve this tripping?

Can you go down to the central vacuum unit and make sure the motor spins freely by hand?

I just looked at the unit and the motor is encased within the steel cannister. looks like i will have to figure out to remove the casing to get to the motor.

Test a workaround: Spin it up for 20 seconds, shut it and wait a minute or two, then start the vac again.

Ok will try that. I might have to wait for a couple of days. Since i used the vacuum today and tripped within the first 2 minutes, it wouldn't trip again if i test now.

I tried that today. The breaker tripped again. I probably waited under a min. Not sure if I should have waited more. Also, when we used the vacuum in the afternoon after about 2 hours break, it tripped the breaker again. Not sure what is going on.

No luck. Tried spinning it up for abt 20 seconds and waited for abt 5 minutes and turned it on again. Still tripped the breaker within abt a minute.

It’s either the vac or the breaker.  Try swapping with another 20 amp in your panel.  Open the main breaker before you remove the panel, and steer clear of the incoming power to the main.
If the problem goes away, it’s the breaker.  It may function OK with the different load on the other circuit.  If it’s flaky in two places, replace it for sure.

will try that and see how it goes
